# How to Enable Zoom in Background Image?

Tags: html, css

I have created a example with keyframe to zoom in and out background image. It's work but also zooming inner text.

I just need the Background Image to be Zoomed. So that images differ from each other and user will get chance to zoom background image.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
    ;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% { }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;

  }
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
    ;
  }
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5px 1000px;

  }
}

div{
  width:100%; 
  height:100vh;
  background-image:
    url('http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/3d-live-wallpaper-free-download-1.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  animation: zoom 30s infinite;
  text-align:center;
}
h1{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:50px;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% { transform:scale(1,1); }
  50% { transform:scale(1.2,1.2); }
  100% {
    transform:scale(1,1); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>OVER TEXT</h1>
  <a href="http://wallpaperlatest.com/free-live-wallpapers-download/">Image Souce:</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying the **transform** property to the parent div. Alternatively, you can modify the background size of the parent div in your **zoom** keyframe, and adjust the size & positioning from there.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
    ;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% { }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;

  }
}
@-ms-keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px, 0px 0px, 0px 0px }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
    ;
  }
}
@keyframes snow {
  0% { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  50% {  }
  100% {
    background-position: 5px 1000px;

  }
}

div{
  width:100%; 
  height:100vh;
  background-image:
    url('http://wallpaperlatest.com/wp-content/uploads/3d-live-wallpaper-free-download-1.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  animation: zoom 30s infinite;
  text-align:center;
}
h1{
  color:#fff;
  font-size:50px;
}
@keyframes zoom {
  0% { 
    background-size: 100%; 
  }
  50% { 
    background-size: 150%; 
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 100%; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>OVER TEXT</h1>
  <a href="http://wallpaperlatest.com/free-live-wallpapers-download/">Image Souce:</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh..!! I got it now.. :) Thanks a lot... @Ryan

Comment: Always happy to help! :)